# Unknown date format from API response

Tags: php, json

API Server responds with token expiration date in the following format:
`2022-05-09T02:11:27.747`
What format is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's ISO-8601 standard time format.  Year month day T hour minute second millisecond.  The `date_parse` function will  handle this.

```
<?php

$x = '2021-04-01T19:18:17.654';
print_r(date_parse($x));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2021
    [month] => 4
    [day] => 1
    [hour] => 19
    [minute] => 18
    [second] => 17
    [fraction] => 0.654
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```